# AVCaptureSession and AVAssetWriter different settings

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

In the case of writing to file from camera using `AVAssetWriting` and setting, for example `AVVideoWidth` to 1280 and `AVVideoHeight` to 720, but use video settings for `AVCAptureSession` as `AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480` (or any other resolutions).
Will the video in the end be encoded in `AVAssetWriter`'s settings or rather `AVCaptureSession`'s settings will be applied?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up an `AVCaptureSession` you define the format that `AVFoundation` delivers to a client(== your app).
So a capture session is the starting point of your data flow.
`AVAssetWriter` is the final destination of your video data, so ultimately the video will have the format you specified when creating the asset writer.
In between, `AVAssetWriter` will transcode all samples it receives from the format of your capture session to the format you specified for your `AVAssetWriterInput` (in the `outputSettings` dict)

Comment: that sounds legit.so, it seems that the resulting video will be 1280x720 even when the source was 640x480